# Connecting TTL-232R-5V-PCB to STM32F103C8T6A bluepill via OTG and installing boot to this STM32 microcontroller

Tags: usb, stm32, uart, bootloader, stm

I have TTL-232R-5V-PCB and STM32F103C8T6A bluepill board. I am working on installing bootloader to this bluepill board on that way, I have searched on the web about it but all people connected them via jumpers from TTL to some pins of STM32 bluepill board. Could it possible to connect in this way?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is unknown what that adapter of yours does, but you can't connect with an UART to the F103 USB pins for any useful purpose.